# Assign value for each label name

Tags: vb.net

Can someone teach me how to assign a value for each label with the same name?.
For example, I have a 10 label with the name label1 until label10. On each label,i want to show different value from sql. This is my code.

```
Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand("select distinct top 15  Machine_no  from table5 ", conn)
    Dim sqlDa As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
    sqlDa.Fill(dt)

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count
            lblMachine1.text = dt.Rows(0)("Machine_no").ToString)
            lblMachine2.Text = dt.Rows(1)("Machine_no").ToString
            lblMachine3.Text = dt.Rows(2)("Machine_no").ToString
            lblMachine4.Text = dt.Rows(3)("Machine_no").ToString
            lblMachine5.Text = dt.Rows(4)("Machine_no").ToString
            lblMachine6.Text = dt.Rows(5)("Machine_no").ToString
            lblMachine7.Text = dt.Rows(6)("Machine_no").ToString
            lblMachine8.Text = dt.Rows(7)("Machine_no").ToString
            lblMachine9.Text = dt.Rows(8)("Machine_no").ToString
            lblMachine10.Text = dt.Rows(9)("Machine_no").ToString
            lblMachine11.Text = dt.Rows(10)("Machine_no").ToString
            lblMachine12.Text = dt.Rows(11)("Machine_no").ToString
            lblMachine13.Text = dt.Rows(12)("Machine_no").ToString
            lblMachine14.Text = dt.Rows(13)("Machine_no").ToString
            lblMachine15.Text = dt.Rows(14)("Machine_no").ToString
        Next
    End If
```

The problem is, when no data in rows 5 for example, the system will give an error.

Comment: using `For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count` is completely pointless as you are not using `i` anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site!

Before we address your problem, I would like to point out that:

> "The problem is, when no data in rows 5 for example, the system will
>   give an error."

is too broad to really identify your issue.

It would be very helpful to also include the error message you are receiving.

Regarding your real problem, your code can be shortened with the use of `DirectCast`. You can try this one:

```
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            DirectCast(Controls.Find("lblMachine" & i + 1, True)(0), Label).Text = dt.Rows(i).Item("MachineNo").ToString
        Next
    End If
```

Using `For Loop` in your code is a good start but you didn't integrate it at all. In the code above, you can see how `i` is being used.

Also `dt` is a `DataTable` right? `DataTables` are `index-based` so it's starting with `zero(0)`. That's why you can notice in the the `For Loop` statement the `dt.Rows.Count - 1`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow ! Thanks all for your help. I try to follow your answer, but this error come out. Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Check if the number of your labels having `lblMachine` in their names corresponds the number of `MachineNo` in  your database.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `i` as a loop variable but you are not using to reference your labels.

You can try to put your labels in an array and then match them up to a row by index like this:

```
Dim labels = {lblMachine1, lblMachine2, lblMachine3, lblMachine4,...}

Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand("select distinct top 15  Machine_no  from table5 ", conn)
Dim sqlDa As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
sqlDa.Fill(dt)

If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count -1
        dim row= dt.rows(i)
        labels(i).text = row("Machine_no")
    Next
End If
```

You can also use FindControl  for windows formas @Allen points out.  But when using for Web you need to implement a recursive version because the control you are looking for is usually nested within some other control.

```
private FindControlRecursive(control  parent, string id) as control  
   if parent.id=id then return parent
   for each child in parent.controls
       control result = FindControlRecursive(child, id)
       if not result is nothing then return result
   next
end function
```

Then in your code:

```
Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand("select distinct top 15  Machine_no  from table5 ", conn)
Dim sqlDa As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
sqlDa.Fill(dt)

If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count -1
         fincontrolrecursive("lblMachine" + i).text = dt.rows(i)("Machine_no")
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Regarding the nesting in the controls, `Controls.Find` already have that function I guess (correct me if I'm wrong). The parameters for `Controls.Find` are the `key` (first parameter, string, for the control name) and the second is the `searchAllChildren` parameter, which is a `Boolean`, which I already used in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, windows vs web. Web is not recursive. Notice I am using "id" not name. Should have made that clear. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That's why. Made me look back at his post. Tagged as `vb.net`. Anyway, it's better to have options and thanks for the additional knowledge. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I get this error. Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Then you have more rows than labels

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement

Also try searching for:
Vb.net for each control loop

You will more than likely have to make a direct object reference using a `List(Of Label)`

Here is my take on it. Untested.

```
Dim machList As List(Of Label) = New List(Of Label)
For Each label As Label In GroupBox1.Controls
machList.Add(label)
Next label 
        For row As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count
If dt.Row(row) <> Nothing Then
    machList.Index(row).Text = dt.Rows(row)
End If
Next row
```